# To run fuzzy search on text, and no HTTP server

Tags: hibernate, elasticsearch, solr, fuzzy-search, java-10

I am writing a Java SE 10 desktop software application.

I use Hibernate 5.4.2 ORM framework on the embedded Derby DB.

I would like to run **fuzzy** **search** on text, which could be in JSON format or even under the data-base.

I want to do somethng more sophisticated than the "**value LIKE '%key%'**".

For fuzzy search I could use existing libraries (based on Apache Lucene lib), like:

- Apache Solr
- ElasticSearch

But it appears that the libraries require HTTP server to be up-and-running, which I do not want to have under my desktop app.

Is there any other similar library which can do the fuzzy search, which does not need the HTTP server, and under the permissive license such as Apache?

Otherwise, does the Hibernate ORM framework can achieve similar functionality?

Best regards

Comment: Have a look at [Hibernate Search](http://hibernate.org/search/). I believe it is configured to use embedded Lucene by default

Comment: You could implement Lucene directly, or you could use EmbeddedSolrServer if you need other services offered by Solr on top of Lucene.